# Are all tree objects made when commit?

Tags: git

I'm wondering that:

1. Are all *tree* object made when committed(maybe `commit-tree` in plumbing?).
2. Then why *tree* objects(especially for directories) are not made in adding to index whereas *blobs* are?

I figured out *blobs* are made when I add files to index.

```sh
git init
mkdir test-dir
echo "File1" > test-dir/test.txt
git count-objects
# 0 objects, 0 kilobytes
git add test-dir/test.txt
git count-objects
# 1 objects, 4 kilobytes
git ls-files -s
# 100644 03f128cf48cb203d938805e9f3e13b808d1773e9 0       test-dir/test.txt
```

But I can't find *tree* object for `test-dir` until commit.

```sh
git commit -m "my first commit"
# [master (root-commit) 48448a5] my first commit
# 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
# create mode 100644 test-dir/test.txt
git count-objects
# 4 objects, 16 kilobytes
git rev-list --all --objects
# 48448a5c6d04cbcd6ab25b64c4bbab9dec5fcf94
# 5f618720e3fc14d396086feb6ee1d869fbbf2e21
# 3bdfe0bec6b5140848283e5e55fc0edd9bb52b32 test-dir
# 03f128cf48cb203d938805e9f3e13b808d1773e9 test-dir/test.txt
git cat-file -t 3bdfe0
# tree
git cat-file -p 3bdfe0
# 100644 blob 03f128cf48cb203d938805e9f3e13b808d1773e9    test.txt
```

Now I get *tree* object for `test-dir` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree objects get built by `git write-tree`.  That is, `git commit` consists of several sub-commands (see notes below):

```
git write-tree
git commit-tree <parents> <message> <tree-hash-ID>
git update-ref <full-ref> <commit-hash-ID>
```

The first command, which takes no parameters, turns the *index* (use `git ls-files --stage` to view its contents) into a series of tree objects.  The top level tree object's hash ID is printed to its standard output.

The second command needs parameters: `-p` for each parent commit hash ID, `-m` or `-F` to supply the commit log message, and the tree hash ID printed by `git write-tree`.  It produces the commit object's hash ID as its standard output.

The last command also needs parameters: the full name of the current branch (e.g., `refs/heads/master`), or the name `HEAD` if `HEAD` is currently detached from any branch, and the commit hash ID produced by the second command.  It updates the given ref to hold the given hash ID.  If the ref is a branch name, or `HEAD`, the hash ID should be that of a commit.

#### Notes

Originally, `git commit` was a small shell script that simply ran these three commands (with appropriate shell glue).  At that time, `git commit` did not have as many options and flags and modes as it does now.

Eventually `git commit` became a single C program.  It now does all these parts internally.  It also handles locking, runs pre-commit hooks, and other such things; these can't be done properly in a shell script using the three individual commands.  The three individual commands do still remain, however, so that you can use them to build your own scripts, if you like.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation :). So can I conclude that **index** does not hold any tree object but only **blobs**, and all needed(If there isn't same one) **tree** objects are made when `write-tree` stage. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct. Note that blob and tree objects can both be re-used: if the data match up 100% with some existing object, you'll get the hash ID of the existing object and no *new* object goes into the object database; you just re-use the existing object.